# Use CPagination with createCommand function in Yii framework

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I am trying to use CPagination.The example shown here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination is using criteria. I am using stored procedure for selecting the data. The database used is postgresql. I am calling the stored procedure using create command function.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select sp_images_select(:project_id,:milestone_id);");
$command->bindParam(":project_id",$this->project_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->bindParam(":milestone_id",$this->milestone_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$command->queryAll();
```

How can I use CPagination with the result set of this command. I am using ajax to display the image gallery as explained here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only if you can apply `Limit` (maximum records to retrieve)
and `Offset` (from which record to start)  in some way to the stored procedure.

Let's go step by step through the example and analyze what is needed

**Your Yii controller for the images**

```
function actionIndex(){
    //Not needed, you apply criteria in your stored procedure with the 
    //arguments of your stored procedure.
    //$criteria=new CDbCriteria();

    // In some way you have to be able to determine how many records will 
    // be returned by the stored procedure when no limits are set 
    // (your challenge).
    $count= ..; // challenge here

    // create pagination object
    $pages=new CPagination($count);

    // Results per page, configure the maximum number of rows to be 
    // displayed (the limit).
    $pages->pageSize=10;

    // Set the page you are on. Either the starting page (0) or the page 
    // when the action is called by the linker (clicking on a button to 
    // go to a certanin page). The linker will send the page using get.
    // Pages are zero based so you have to decrease the received page by 
    // 1. 
    $pages->currentPage = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page']-1 : 0)

    // You can not use this. This method applies the criteria to a plain 
    // vanilla query (not a stored procedure) and extends that query with 
    // a limit and offset.
    //$pages->applyLimit($criteria);
    // Instead, you retrieve the limit and offset from the pagination 
    // object and pass it to your stored procdure. F.i.
    $command->bindParam(":limit",$pages->limit,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $command->bindParam(":offset",$pages->offset,PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // Get the the images with the stored procedure.
    $images=$command->queryAll();

    // Display the images using a view
    $this->render('index', array(
    'images' => $images,
         'pages' => $pages
    ));
}
```

So, this is what you have to do if you want to use the aforementioned approach:

- find out if your stored procedure supports `Limit` and `Offset`
- if so, extend the arguments of the stored pocedure to receive `Limit` and `Offset` and apply it
- find a way to determine the number of records the stored procedure would result in when `Limit` and `Offset` are not set. This is needed so the pagination object can calculate the `Offset` based on the current page

Hope this will get you on track...

Comment: Thanks.I was able to do the pagination by using CSqlDataProvider.Now the problem is I am using renderPartial() to display the contents of this view using ajax inside another view. But when I click on the pagination links it is going to the action. Ajax is not working.